# Can I stain interior concrete block foundation walls?

Tags: concrete, basement, staining, basement-refinishing, concrete-block

I was planning on painting our basement block walls until I just recently learned of the problems painting concrete invites (mainly mold) from basement waterproofing professionals (Crawl Space Ninja, Wise Waterproofing), and now I am looking for other options.

Would a water based concrete stain or dye avoid these issues? Would there be issues of color transfer/staining of things that come in contact with the wall? Would such a dye compromise the wall integrity?

Comment: "Would there be issues of color transfer/staining of things that come in contact with the wall?" once it dries, how would it? "Would such a dye compromise the wall integrity?" in what way might it? You're planning on using something designed for concrete, I can't imagine that it would harm the substrate it was designed to go on...

Comment: An acid based solution is designed to go on concrete but affects the integrity of the concrete; I didn't see how a water based solution would cause damage, but I make no assumptions when I don't have the direct knowledge. And there are lots of color mediums that leave transferable particles on the surface once dry, unless they are sealed, which I want to avoid.